# How to quickly send commands to nested tmux sessions?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have the following in my .tmux.conf

```
set -g prefix M-j
bind-key j  send-prefix
```

I need to press (<kbd>Atl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) + (<kbd>J</kbd>) + bound-key to send something to the nested tmux session. I feel it is rather slow. Is there any better way? For example, I would love to be able to do (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) + (2x bound-key) to do stuff in the nested session. I constantly execute commands in the top tmux session instead of executing them in the nested one.
Also, how come everybody binds `prefix` to `C-a`? I find it awfully slow and unpleasant to type this combination. Am I missing something?

Comment: While I don't like Ctrl-A either, your comment about its unpleasantness suggests that your pinky is reaching down to the control key maybe.   If so, you might consider remapping capslock as a control key -- this is what I do to keep my finger-twisting under control, and then Ctrl+A is also less challenging.

Comment: @Stabledog your assumption is right. Nevertheless, I mapped capslock to ESC. How do you press capslock + a?

Comment: The C-a combo lives on from GNU Screen, which predates tmux.

Comment: map capslock to esc on tap and ctrl on hold. use ctrl+s that way you only have to move one finger to press your prefix if using standard qwerty home row layout...

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/finger-splits

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is one less keypress to send a command to your nested session if you choose a different key. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> for my standard prefix, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> for nested sessions.

```
# set prefix key to ctrl+t
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-t

# send the prefix to client inside window
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
```

Note that I use the `-n` switch. From the bind-key entry in `man tmux`:

> if -n is specified, it is not necessary to use the prefix key, command is bound to key alone.

So, as an example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> opens a new window in tmux; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> does the same in the nested session.

Comment: Awesome! This makes nested session actually as fast a normal sessions.

Comment: There is no need to unbind `C-b` if you got used to it. `bind-key -n C-a send-prefix` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for ctrl-a is that most Unix hackers (that I know at least) remap caps lock to control. That makes all ctrl- ops faster, especially ctrl-a.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in a previous comment above: How on earth do you people press capslock+a at the same time? I use the pinky to either press one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can disable controls of the outer `tmux` session. Most of the time I want to control the inner session, so I use <kbd>F12</kbd> as [toggle hotkey](https://gist.github.com/samoshkin/05e65f7f1c9b55d3fc7690b59d678734).