# How to execute TMUX commands on a remote server when I have TMUX running locally too?

Tags: tmux

I am not sure if this is possible but I have a remote server running `tmux` and I frequently `ssh` into that server from a computer that is also running `tmux`.

The issue is that the `tmux.conf` filed are the same so when I try to run a command like `detach` with `prefix-d` I detach from my local `tmux` session when I actually want to detach from the remote one.

I do not see anyway around this other than having separate `tmux.conf` files but I thought I would check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have nested `tmux` sessions, it is the first ("outermost", oldest) that gets the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> key sequence to detach.

You can set up `tmux` to send its prefix key to the "inner" session like this (in your `~/.tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key b send-prefix
```

This will send the prefix <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (or whatever you use as prefix) when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is basically "the prefix for the inner (of two) `tmux` sessions".

Sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will then detach the inner `tmux` session.

Splitting the pane of the innermost session: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

The above assumes *two* nested sessions. Detaching the innermost of *three* sessions: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

To simplify this, set up a separate "prefix" for nested sessions as [explained in the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130732/116858) to a similar question.